# SCN issue for older oracle servers

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

I am new to this, therefore need some help:

We are using PeopleTools 8.48, Peoplesoft Enterprise 8.8 for CRM application.  We have database of Oracle v10.2.0.5.0.  Recently, because of SCN issue, we have been asked to apply the following patches- Patch 14121009 + patch 16619894 DBPSU (July 2013 PSU).

my question- are these patches compatible with the PeopleSoft/PeopleTool and Oracle versions?  Do we need to make any upgrades in parallel?

Comment: Possibly, this question would get a more suited audience on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.oracle.com/security-alerts/cpujan2013.html the DBPSU you are referring to looks more relevant to versions 8.51 and 8.52 for Peoplesoft/Peopletools.

So whilst it *might* work, you would definitely want to seek clarification from Oracle Support before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

as for Oracle database version, the patch is compatible.
Don't forget to select the database version you're on on the patch download page. 
v 10.2.0.5 is in the list.

As for People Soft version you're on, this is has to be cleared with Oracle Support. Right as Connor says.
I'd recommend you to log an SR at MyOracleSupport with compatibility question. Normally, they're quick enough with such kind of answers.